# How to get location of a sprite in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame

I am making a game in Python using Pygame. I have put a condition where if the player character goes on a specified tile than the score will increment by 1. but I am not able to get it done. because I am not able to get the position of the player character.for example if player_position == (the specified tile) : than score=score+1. please help me with this.

Comment: It's hard to give you an answer if you don't provide any examples. It becomes too much guess work. Try creating a [mcve] and edit it into the question. You should be able to make it work if you loop through all tiles and then check if the player's rect intersect with the tile's rect, using [`player.rect.colliderect(tile.rect)`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect), assuming each tile and the player has an attribute `rect` that is a [Rect object](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html).

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using one of the "collide" functions? You could make the tile a sprite, too, and detect the collision. It might not be exactly what you're looking for, but it could work.

This would return True when two sprite arguments collide. 
pygame.sprite.collide_rect()

Comment: I've tried it! but not happening. :( any other options??? i don't know how make a tile a sprite. i tried to use the location of tile but it did not work.

Comment: `pygame.sprite.collide_rect` is intended to be passed to `pygame.sprite.spritecollide`'s  `collided` argument. You can use just `pygame.sprite.spritecollide` to check collision between sprites because if you omit the `collided` argument it'll default to check if the rect's intersect.